# Calling cublasDgetrfBatched to perform LU decomposition failed with Pycuda

Tags: cuda, pycuda, scikit-cuda

I want to do a LU decomposition of a square matrix A by using scikit-cuda and pycuda. I tried a few demo code from the scikit-cuda github website and all seemed fine.

However, when I tried to call the low-level interface cublas.cublasDgetrfBatched in my little example, I failed with the error code below:

```
PyCUDA WARNING: a clean-up operation failed (dead context maybe?)
cuMemFree failed: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Here is my little python code

```py
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import skcuda.cublas as cublas
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray

N = 10
N_BATCH = 1  # only 1 matrix to be decomposed
A_SHAPE = (N, N)

a = np.random.rand(*A_SHAPE).astype(np.float64)
a_batch = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a_batch.T.copy())  # transpose a to follow "F" order
p_gpu = gpuarray.zeros(N * N_BATCH, np.int32)
info_gpu = gpuarray.zeros(N_BATCH, np.int32)

cublas_handle = cublas.cublasCreate()
cublas.cublasDgetrfBatched(
    cublas_handle,
    N,
    a_gpu.gpudata,
    N,
    p_gpu.gpudata,
    info_gpu.gpudata,
    N_BATCH,
)

cublas.cublasDestroy(cublas_handle)
print(a_gpu)
```

I am a novice user of scikit-cuda. So, could someone give me a hand?

Comment: The documentation (such as it is) says that the input is an " array of n x n matrices". So I am guessing you have the wrong input form. The underlying CUBLAS routine uses an array of pointers as an input, I suspect this might work the same

Comment: @talonmies thanks for the comment. "array of pointers" is the part that confuses me. In my little example I am using a 3-dimensional array -- a list (pointer) of 2d matrices. What the "right form" of the input should look like?

Comment: "I am using .... a list (pointer) of 2d matrices". But I don't think you are. You have a 2D array which you have expanded into 3D. That isn't what is expected. I *guess* you need something like `np.array([int(mat0.gpudata), int(mat1.gpudata), ....])` copied to the GPU as the input, where `mat0`, `mat1` are the batch matrices already on the GPU. Unfortunately I can't test any of this myself to check, but the source shows it is an extremely thin wrapper around a ctypes call to the CUBLAS routine. It is completely unaware of any numpy/PyCuda metadata about dimensions/shapes, etc

Comment: @talonmies good point. I am gonna give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @talonmies most of your point is valid and with that I figured out what was wrong with my little example. The key is that cublasDgetrfBatched is expecting a pointer to the device memory that has **a list of pointers** to matrices on GPU. What I did wrong  was that I used a pointer to the device memory that has a batch of matrices on GPU.

Comment: Again, what you have written in this comment and what the code in the answer does are not the same. There is no list, you cannot pass a list as an argument to any of these functions. You are passing a gpuarray.gpudata , I.e. an array, not a list

Comment: array it is!...I agree and should have been more careful on the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Like @talonmies commented, a pointer to an array of address of matrix on the device should be used.

```py
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import skcuda.cublas as cublas
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray

N = 10
N_BATCH = 1  # only 1 matrix to be decomposed
A_SHAPE = (N, N)

a = np.random.rand(*A_SHAPE).astype(np.float64)
a_batch = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a_batch.T.copy()))  # transpose a to follow "F" order

# use np.array won't work instead of gpuarray.to_gpu.
# .ptr is pointer to matrix a on the device
# can be further revised to programmatically create an array of pointers 
a_gpu_batch = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.asarray([a_gpu.ptr]) 

p_gpu = gpuarray.zeros(N * N_BATCH, np.int32)
info_gpu = gpuarray.zeros(N_BATCH, np.int32)

cublas_handle = cublas.cublasCreate()
cublas.cublasDgetrfBatched(
    cublas_handle,
    N,
    a_gpu_batch.gpudata,
    N,
    p_gpu.gpudata,
    info_gpu.gpudata,
    N_BATCH,
)

cublas.cublasDestroy(cublas_handle)
print(a_gpu)
```